# Как отправить изображение base64 в Postman

Tags: mongodb, base64, postman

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Нужно сделать запрос к API с изображением, закодированным в base64. Хочу присвоить параметру `Фото` строку `base64` через Get-запрос, но возникает ошибка!

Answer (score 4):

body -> raw, туда вставляй {{Фото1}}, которое уже закодировано в base64